# What's the relation between stand-alone flashplayer and browser plugin used to play flash?

Tags: browser-addons, flash-player

Are they the same ?

Is it possible that one has installed the stand-alone flashplayer(`flashplayer.exe xx.swf` works) but can't play the `xx.swf` in the browser?

Comment: FF, IE, Opera or ...?

Comment: I'm targetting various browsers on mobile phones.

Comment: given the new direction of the question you may want to as about targeting devices for flash on programming not superuser

Comment: Suggest you take this question to Stack Overflow, it seems to actually be a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The plug-in is what tells you browser to which application to send that mime type and what kind of data it should expect in return...no, not the same

Comment: Do mobile browsers all have flash plugin except those on iphone?

Comment: not part of the original question...my opinion is (flash == evil) returns true, so I try not to use it at all - specifically more so for mobile web.

Comment: Not all mobile browsers support Flash--notably, the BlackBerry browser (still the largest market share) does not.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but mainly because the flashplayer plugin exists as a separate program, usually libflashplayer.so.  For the browser plugin to work on embedded or phone systems it will need to use the same display renderer as the browser.  For Linux based phones, X11 isn't always available so you'd need a custom flashplayer, not the normal Linux one.